# Showing custom markers, shadows and popups from JSON data

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, references, markers

The examples given in the documentation of OpenLayers show very basic ways of utilising the different features. [This](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/marker-shadow.html) example shows how to add shadows to the marker. [This](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/light-basic.html) example shows how to create basic popups.

Looking at the sample code, I have no idea how to combine the two together, nor display different icons for the markers. Can anyone show me a tutorial or example that combines the various aspects of custom markers, shadows and popups using JSON data?

Comment: OpenStreetMap is not the same as OpenLayers. Please edit your question.

Comment: @drnextgis, noted. It's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the OpenLayers Cookbook (http://www.packtpub.com/openlayers-create-gis-web-applications-cookbook/book) has some samples creating markers by hand.

And you can freely download the source code: http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/9781849517843

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The examples look complex enough. Hope to find what I want..